# adding SSL certificate into the https request in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, ssl-certificate

Sorry for lengthy question. So far I used below methods to trust the certificate for HTTPS connection and it works fine.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
  return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
      [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

  [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

But every request to server takes at least 10 to 15 seconds to call these delegate method. Customer raised it as a defect and So i tried to keep the certificate .der in bundle and tried to send cert,trust,policy objects with the request. I used below code to retrive the certificate from .der.

```
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                     pathForResource:@"Mycertificate" ofType:@"der"];
NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc]
                    initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];

CFDataRef myCertData = (__bridge CFDataRef)certData;                 // 1

SecCertificateRef myCert;
myCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, myCertData);    // 2
SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();         // 3

SecCertificateRef certArray[1] = { myCert };
CFArrayRef myCerts = CFArrayCreate(
                                   NULL, (void *)certArray,
                                   1, NULL);
SecTrustRef myTrust;

OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(
                                                 myCerts,
                                                 myPolicy,
                                                 &myTrust);  // 4

SecTrustResultType trustResult;
if (status == noErr) {
    status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);       // 5
    [request setClientCertificates:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)CFBridgingRelease(myCert)]];
}
//...
NSLog(@"myTrust  %@", myTrust);
// 6
if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure) {
    // ...;
}
// ...
if (myPolicy)
    CFRelease(myPolicy);
```

myCerts contain all my certificate objects, myTrust contain my trusted object, myPolicy contain my Policy object. I am sending a request as given below to server

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://....."];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self setURLRequestWithData:requestParam andURL:url];

_theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I dont know how to set the certificates, trust  and policy objects with this request. Please help me in this issue. How to send a request to server in such a way that the request should trust server certificate always. ?? Thanks in advance.